# ¿Cómo encontrar las coordenadas respecto a la imagen- Python?

Tags: python, array, imagen

quiero encontrar valores medios en un área (elipse) del array de datos que he graficado aquí. Pero, aunque puedo calcular esto introduciendo las coordenadas del círculo que me interesa, no sé cómo situar la elipse en la imagen global, ya que no sé cómo hacer la correspondencia entre unas coordenadas y las otras, y me lo sitúa mal.
Me podríais ayudar? Muchas gracias!

P.e.j el centro en el array es: 265,269, pero en la imagen sería algo parecido a 170,125 (a ojo.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].La descripción de tu problema está bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.